# How to Implement Fingerprint Lock Screen in Codenameone

Tags: codenameone, lockscreen, fingerprint

Does anyone have an idea to implementing lock screen that uses fingerprint to unlock the screen on a codenameone app. Any ideas at all will be welcomed. Majority of ideas i have seen are basically cheat concepts that does not implement the concept. You ideas, resources, links etc are welcomed even if it requires a 3rd party service butt I think java native code may be able to do this, i just dont have a clear idea yet.

Comment: Do you mean the global OS lock screen or an "in-app" login screen that uses fingerprint ID?

Comment: Derek, am actually of the opinion that once the OS screen can implemented the same can integrated into an in-app. Although am interested in an in-app. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Global lock screen can't be implemented in Codename One since its very specific to Android and has no portable alternative. You might as well just write a native app.

You will need to write a [native interface](https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html) to access the fingerprint reader hardware:

https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html

https://www.codenameone.com/blog/integrating-3rd-party-native-sdks-part-1.html

Using the native touch ID should be pretty strait forward e.g.: http://www.devfright.com/touch-id-tutorial-objective-c/

Comment: Shai thanks for your response as always. However, may I ask (rhetorical though) "Writing a native interface for the finger print reader hardware" Can i assume that the mobile phone can act as the fingerprint reader hardware? Considering the fact that I want to use the basic mobile phone that we see around now with regards to the mobile phone camera specifically, should I take it that the mobile phone camera can function as the fingerprint reader hardware in this case. Thanks for your more enlightenment. Better still an example or similar tutorial in this regards will go a very long way

Comment: That's unlikely. Fingerprint reading is pretty hard and requires dedicated hardware.

Comment: But based on your previous post and in the link resource " http://www.devfright.com/touch-id-tutorial-objective-c/" Dont you think the concept is achievable using Touch ID at least on iOS. I have gone over it and it looks so though i have not began to try it out.

Comment: With touch id it will work but not with the camera. The touch ID requires  dedicated hardware and won't work on all iOS devices.